# Preferred fallback network interfaces with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant

My Vagrant boxes use public networking so they can advertise themselves over zeroconf/Bonjour. The `Vagrantfile` explicitly sets the bridged network interface:

```rb
  config.vm.network :public_network, :bridge => 'en2: USB Ethernet'
```

Most of the time everything just works, but if I'm connected via a different network and the specified interface doesn't exist, `vagrant up` will prompt me to pick from the available network interfaces:

```
[default] Specific bridge 'en2: USB Ethernet' not found. You may be asked to specify
which network to bridge to.
[default] Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
2) p2p0
What interface should the network bridge to?
```

Is there a way to tell Vagrant to choose from a list of preferred network interfaces? What I want is a graceful fallback if the primary network isn't available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with that seems to be working well so far:

In `Vagrantfile`, add the following to the top of the file:

```rb
pref_interface = ['en2: USB Ethernet', 'en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)']
vm_interfaces = %x( VBoxManage list bridgedifs | grep ^Name ).gsub(/Name:\s+/, '').split("\n")
pref_interface = pref_interface.map {|n| n if vm_interfaces.include?(n)}.compact
$network_interface = pref_interface[0]
```

Then, inside `Vagrant.configure`, use `$network_interface` to specify the bridge:

```rb
config.vm.network :public_network, :bridge => $network_interface
```

Comment: Cool, but what about just setting up a Vagrantfile in your ~/.vagrant.d/ that specifies a global default instead of looking at available options each time with the ruby you posted?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great tip. I added 'en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)' to the list because in my mac is en1